# Using Shellsort to sort a list of countries by population (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, shellsort

In my program, I have a class Sorting, that inputs a file called CountryUnsortedFormat that contains a random list of countries and their populations. The class is supposed to use shellsort to sort the countries by population and display them on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
package assignment3;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //Array for handling list of countries
    String[] line = new String[238];
    //read list of countries into array
    readInArray(line);
    //unsort the array
    unSort(line);


}

 static void readInArray(String[] line) throws Exception{
     Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Vicki/Desktop/CountrySortedFormat.txt"));

     //Read in countries from sorted file into an array
    int k=0;
    while (stdIn.hasNextLine()){    
        line[k]=stdIn.nextLine();   
        k++;
    }
 }

 static void unSort(String[] line) throws Exception{
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/Vicki/Desktop/CountryUnsortedFormat.txt");
    //Pick a random int from 1 to 238 called where
    //Write where into Unsorted Country Format file
    //Make where null
    //Repeat until all 238 countries are written in random order
    int j = line.length-1;
    Random r = new Random();
    while (j > 0){
        int where = r.nextInt(j)+1;
        out.println(line[where]);
        line = pop(where, line);
        j--;
    }
    out.close();

 }

 static String[] pop(int index, String[] line){
     String[] newLine = new String[line.length-1];
     int offset = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i<line.length; i++){
         if(i == index){
             offset = 1;
             continue;
         }
         newLine[i - offset] = line[i];
     }
     return newLine;
 }

}

class Sorting {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    //Array for handling list of countries
    String[] line = new String[238];

    readInArray(line);
    shellsort(line);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));

}

static void readInArray(String[] line) throws Exception{
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Vicki/Desktop/CountryUnsortedFormat.txt"));

    //Read in countries from unsorted file into an array
    int k=0;
    while (stdIn.hasNextLine()){    
        line[k]=stdIn.nextLine();   
        k++;
    }
}

static void shellsort(String[] line){
    int j;
    for(int gap = line.length-1/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2){
        for(int i = gap; i < line.length-1; i++){
            String tmp = line[i];
            for (j = i; j >= gap && getPopulation(line, j-gap) > getPopulation(line, i); j -= gap){
                line[j] = line[j -gap];
            }
            line[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

static int getPopulation(String[] line, int index){
    String populationString = line[index].substring(50,65).trim().replaceAll(",","");
    int population = Integer.parseInt(populationString);
    return population;
}


}
```

My classes work separately but when put together my program doesn't print to the screen. All it shows is "BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing I saw that you are reading and writing to the same file. Are you sure that it works as planned?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What happens when you use `System.out.println()`? What do you mean *NetBeans wouldn't print to the screen*?

Comment: How do I sort the countries by their populations using Shellsort? I was writing to the same file because for some reason I couldn't print to the screen to see if I had sorted the countries correctly.

Comment: Ha! NullPointerException? You're definitely not setting `line` correctly then. See the edit to my post regarding debugging and then I highly encourage you to try and solve this yourself.

Comment: You're right there is definitely something wrong with how I'm setting line. I started a different file with just the while loop reading in the file into an array and when I printed it's giving me a half filled loop, with the last values being null.

Comment: So if you look back to your scramble, you're not actually scrambling the thing correctly. That's why you don't have all 238 countries and are ending up with nulls. That should be an `if(line[where] != null)` with the `j--;` inside the braces. Look back to my answer for how to properly implement shuffles.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty obviously a homework assignment, and it'd be wrong to help you further. I would first organize your code into a more readable format. Eg:

```
public class Country{
    private int population;
    public Country(String line){
       // parse and set population
    }
    public int getPopulation(){
       return population;
    }
}
```

then implement the sort

```
# Sort an array countires[0...n-1].
# Start with the largest gap and work down to a gap of 1 
int j;
for(int gap = countries.length/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2){
    # Do a gapped insertion sort for this gap size.
    # The first gap elements countries[0..gap-1] are already in gapped order
    # keep adding one more element until the entire array is gap sorted 
    for(int i = gap; i < line.length; i++){
        # add countries[i] to the elements that have been gap sorted
        # save countries[i] in temp and make a hole at position i
        int temp = countries[i].getPopulation();
        # shift earlier gap-sorted elements up until the correct location for countries[i] is found
        for (j = i; j >= gap && a[j - gap].getPopulation() > temp; j -= gap){
            countries[j] = countries[j - gap]
        }
        # put temp (the original countries[i]) in its correct location
        countries[j] = temp
    }
}
```

Which is more or less ripped directly from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort), and what you have....

This looks like a case of needing better debugging. Drop some breakpoints or some `println`s in populating `line`. There's a chance Netbeans isn't printing anything, because there is nothing to print out. Or you could simply be messing up your parsing. You have hard-coded values in there for your substrings and chances are that's where it's breaking. Using a regex or scanner could solve this problem, simply by not being an *an unholy cluster of functions*. I don't know what your input looks like so I couldn't tell you. However, I know your sort works because I copy and pasted with some random values and ran it myself:

```
class Sorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        int[] line = new int[]{97,95,66,91,33,91,73,63,67,84,40,34,85,43,73,8,45,14,86,23,74,22,50,33,4,75,12,28,44,43,20,69,95,28,8,44,5,21,50,53,83,53,93,4,62,45,24,57,41,30,32,21,44,76,42,85,35,36,20,96,95,35,5,49,21,43,29,97,69,15,40,15,82,73,24,30,53,50,73,2,86,25,35,50,83,15,66,80,36,22,46,34,89,18,15,59,99,85,12,65};

        int j;
        for(int gap = line.length/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2){
            for(int i = gap; i < line.length; i++){
                int population = line[i];
                for (j = i; j >= gap && line[j - gap] > population; j -= gap){
                    line[j] = line[j -gap];
                }
                line[j] = population;
            }
        }
        for (int l : line) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
}
```

The lack of error log <s>sounds like an environmental issue, or might</s> comes down to what you unsorted file looks like, which is most likely wrong since I attempted to answer your previous question which you have since deleted

### Traversing Through Array Using A Random Int and Unsorting a File

So the difficulty with your code as is that you will not end up with a shuffled array. Instead you will have probably duplicates. Let's run through this with an array of 4 `lines = ["Argentina","Barbados","Canada","Dominica"]`

Iteration 1. `j = 4`, let's have `where = 2` and therefore `out = "Canada"`

Iteration 2. `j = 3`, **there's nothing to stop** `where = 2` **again** as such, `out = "Canada, Canada"`

To properly scramble your array, I would recommend **popping the chosen value** To prevent duplicates. Given you are using a plain old array and not an ArrayList you should have a function pop (although I would suggest using an ArrayList):

```
// pop(2,["Argentina","Barbados","Canada","Dominica"]) == ["Argentina","Barbados","Dominica"]
function String[] pop(int index, String[] list){
     newList = new String[list.length - 1]
     int offset = 0;
     for(int i; i < list.length; i++){
         if(i == index){
             offset = 1; // Start skipping 
             continue;
         }
         newList[i - offset] = list[i];
     }
     return newList;
}
```

Your new unSort should like:

```
public static void unSort(String[] line) throws Exception{
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Vicki/Desktop/CountryUnsortedFormat.txt"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/Vicki/Desktop/CountryUnsortedFormat.txt");

    int j = line.length; // Opposed to hardcoding 238
    Random r = new Random(); // Let's put random out so we don't have to continuously initialize
    while (j > 0){
        int where = r.nextInt(j);
        out.println(line[where]);
        line = pop(where, line); // get rid of what we just printed
        j--;
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Of course there are other shuffles, for instance: you could perform a [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) on `line` and then print it out after. I don't fully understand what you're directly asking for, but I imagine it's something like this:

```
public static void unSort(String[] line) throws Exception{
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Vicki/Desktop/CountryUnsortedFormat.txt"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/Vicki/Desktop/CountryUnsortedFormat.txt");

    int j = line.length; // Opposed to hardcoding 238
    Random r = new Random(); // Let's put random out so we don't have to continuously initialize
    while (j > 0){
        int where = r.nextInt(line.length);
        if(line[where] != null){
            out.println(line[where]);
            j--;
            line[where] = null;
        }
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Where this guarantees no duplicates. However this has a best case run time of O(n) and a worst case of being an infinite loop.

Comment: I deleted my previous question because I figured out the answer and realized I have a different question. I've included my entire code. Adding a separate class to parse made it more confusing, my code didn't seem to recognize getPopulation() therefore I had trouble calling it. I tried keeping the parsing within this class but it's still not printing to the screen.

Comment: I'd still see my notes on the shuffle since your way is still not very efficient. I would still recommend doing the parsing in a seperate function even if not an entire class, or look into the scanner.nextInt() function which should save you sometime parsing. Is there no stacktrace? Looks like your code might be dying somewhere and thus not printing out anything.